How to evaluate an integral in the form $\int_{E}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|^d}$
If $E\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is Lebesgue-measurable and $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$, then let
$$
\lambda\left(E\right)=\int_{E}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{|x|^d}.
$$
I want to evaluate the integration when $E=B(0,\varepsilon)$, and the textbook says
$$
\lambda\left(B(0,\varepsilon)\right)=H_{d-1}\left(\mathbb{S}^{d-1}\right)\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r}=\infty
$$
where I think $H_{d-1}$ is the Hausdorff measure.
I want to know how to get $\lambda\left(B(0,\varepsilon)\right)=H_{d-1}\left(\mathbb{S}^{d-1}\right)\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{r}$. I first try to understand it under 2-dimension and obviously it is correct, but I failed when it comes to 3-dimension. Can anyone help me?

It's polar coordinates. See page 123 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf. Equation (3.2.28) is exactly what they use to obtain that.

I think I've posted this elsewhere on this site but I can't find it. Letting
$$I_m(R,p)=\int_{\mathbb B^m(0,R)}\frac{1}{|x|^p}\mathrm d^m x$$
You don't even need to know hyperspherical coordinates to evaluate this. All you need to know is the formula for the surface area of the sphere $\partial\mathbb B^m(0,r)=\{x\in\mathbb R^m : |x|=r\}$. It is $A_m r^{m-1}$
where
$$A_m=\frac{2\pi^{m/2}}{\Gamma(m/2)}$$
Is the surface area of $\partial\mathbb B^{m}(0,1)$. We can split our integration domain into spherical shells:
$$I_m(R,p)=\int_0^R \int_{\partial\mathbb B^m(0,r)}\frac{1}{|x|^p}\mathrm d^{m-1}x~\mathrm dr$$
Since the function $x\mapsto |x|^{-p}$ is constant on $\partial\mathbb B^{m}(0,r)$, the inner integral is equal to $r^{-p}~A_mr^{m-1}$ and so
$$I_m(R,p)=A_m\int_0^R r^{m-p-1}~\mathrm dr=\begin{cases}A_m\frac{R^{m-p}}{m-p} & m>\Re p \\ \text{divergent} & m\leq \Re p\end{cases}$$
